# How form data are binding to the DTO class' private members by spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring MVC project where I am getting some data from UI form. I have a DTO class having private members in it. When I submit the form data then the FrontController(Dispatcher Servlet) invokes a method of Controller class because of `@RequestMapping` annotation. In this method, I am passing the reference of DTO class as an argument and printing the value of member variables of DTO class on the console by invoking getter methods.
But I am not understanding how automatically the object of DTO class is creating and the form data are binding to the member variables of the DTO class. Please tell me how it is working?

Controller class

```
package com.soni.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.soni.web.dto.StudentRecordsDTO;

@Component
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentRecords {

    public StudentRecords() {
System.out.println(getClass().getName());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(StudentRecordsDTO studentRecordsDTO) {

    System.out.println(studentRecordsDTO.getId());
    System.out.println(studentRecordsDTO.getName());

    return "/registration_success.html";
   }

}
```

DTO class

```
package com.soni.web.dto;

public class StudentRecordsDTO {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public StudentRecordsDTO(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="signup" method ="post">
<input type  = "num" name="id">
<input type = "text" name="name">
<input type = "password" name="pwd">
<input type = "num" name = "nm">
<input type = "submit" value="press">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using POST method, anything you send as part of BODY (JSON data) is converted to POJO (plain old java object) i.e. StudentRecordsDTO in this case, of argument of your signup() method.

You if you json data is which you sending from your client looks like something this

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Chirag"
}
```

Then internally when JSON Deserialization happen, More on Serialization/Deserialization [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

"**id**" is mapped to "**id**" property in the class and uses setter method using java convention to set the value to the object.

Similarly, "**name**" is mapped to "**name**" property in the class.

So, internally you can think of like this.

```
StudentRecordsDTO studentRecordsDTO = new StudentRecordsDTO();
studentRecordsDTO.setId(1);
studentRecordsDTO.setName("Chirag")
```

and this studentRecordsDTO object is passed to your controller method with value set as what you are passing.

You can also use @RequestBody here for readability.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(RequestBody StudentRecordsDTO studentRecordsDTO) {

  System.out.println(studentRecordsDTO.getId());
  System.out.println(studentRecordsDTO.getName());

  return "/registration_success.html";
}
```

So spring does this for you in background. You can also look at

@RequestHeader to set the header passed as part of request directly. 
@RequestParam to extra the request param in case of GET method.

There are various other abstraction (and customization) spring provides so you can concentrate on core business logic.